# Provisioning Android Device with SIP Account

Tags: android, sip, voip, telephony

Do any of you experts know if there is a way to provision an Android Device for the creation of a SIP account?

Lets say I have a company, with 100 members of staff. Each staff member is given an Android device and asked to setup a SIP Account via the settings.

You can imagine this would not go down well with some "less technical" individuals and so I would like to bypass this DIY step and just do it all via some sort of automated process.

I found this article: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/admin/provision.html

But doesn't mention the provisioning of SIP accounts.

Does anyone know anything about this?

NB: I am used to provisioning Polycom devices via XML so this is not a "please tell me everything" question, more of a "can you point me in the right direction" one ;-)

Comment: You can create a SIP programmatically but I don't think that will meet your requirements - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipProfile.Builder.html

Comment: Yeh I have seen that documentation already... hoping to do this a little smarter. May have to open a bounty!